# Is it possible/ How to add fade out transition animation on text that changes into an image after 3.5 seconds in swiftui?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, swiftui

I am trying to do an animation that fades Text out into an Image on swiftui on app launch and everytime the user goes back into the app even if it's in the background

how can i do so?

I have tried .onappear and dispatchqueue but it does not seem to work

This is my code

```
var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.937254902, green: 0.937254902, blue: 0.937254902, alpha: 1))
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
                
                ScrollView{
                    
                    VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: -10) {
                      //  Text("\(tickerListVM.netProfit)")
                        
                        Text("Welcome Back, String Interpolation")
                            .font(.largeTitle)
                            .bold()
                            .padding()
                           
                       
//                        Image("moon")
//                            .resizable()
//                              .frame(width: 375.0, height: 200.0)
                        
                        OverallView()
                            .padding()
                            .environmentObject(tickerListVM)
                        
                        NavigationLink(destination: MonthlyGoalSetView()) {
                        CurrentMonthlyGoalView()
                        }
                        .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                  
                      
                        LastMonthsGoalView()
                        
                        
                        NavigationLink(destination: YearlyGoalSetView()) {
                        YearlyGoalView()
                        }
                        .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                        .padding(.bottom, 10)
                        
                        
                        HorizontalCardListView(title:"Profits")
                            .padding(.leading)
                            .padding(.trailing)
                            .environmentObject(tickerListVM)
                        
                        HorizontalCardListView(title:"Loses")
                            .padding()
                            .environmentObject(tickerListVM)
                    }
                    
                    
                    
                }
                .navigationBarHidden(true)
            }
        }
    }
}



struct HomeView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        HomeView()
            .environmentObject(TickerListViewModel())
    }
}
```

and this is what it looks like right now

[current view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XvcPx.png)

ideally, i would like the top text to fade out into an image like this onlaunch and each time the user goes back into the app after 3.5 seconds

Please let me know how i can do so, thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You need to simplify the code shown, and actually put views that work. Currently your code contains views like `CurrentMonthlyGoalView` that we don't have.

Comment: Hi, I have excluded it for simplicity. The only relevant code to be looking at is 

Text("Welcome Back, String Interpolation")
                            .font(.largeTitle)
                            .bold()
                            .padding()
                           
                       and 

//                        Image("moon")
//                            .resizable()
//                              .frame(width: 375.0, height: 200.0)

Comment: You still do not have a minimal, reproducible example. Please take your posted code and paste it in a new app. Then try to build and run it and you will understand what I am saying.  You really need to remove anything that does not directly  relate or affect your question.